# Embed Power BI Report Full Javascript

Tags: javascript, embed, embedding, powerbi

I want to embed a Power BI Report using the REST API. So anyone knows how to make the authentication process trought javascript, ie get the access token, because the example of the Power BI documentation is done in C#. If someone know something would be helpful! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see a pure JavaScript example is that it wouldn't be secure. To complete the workflow you'd need to pass the client secret to the auth endpoint. In JavaScript that would be stored in plain text on the page. Not good.  So use a server workflow. There are [libraries for plenty of programming languages](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-libraries/) if C# is not your thing.  If you're building a client app, there's a client workflow that does not require a server backend, but that's not appropriate for a web page.

Comment: I disagree with you if we are only talking about JavaScript. People may want to do it using node.js on the server side.